Why is WidgetStatePropertyAll not recognized?
WidgetStatePropertyAll is giving me error. However it was working in a different system. I have upgraded my flutter to latest version Flutter version 3.22.0 (stable)
Code is as follows:
class ForgotPasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ForgotPasswordPage> createState() => _ForgotPasswordPageState();
}

class _ForgotPasswordPageState extends State<ForgotPasswordPage> {
  void _passwordReset(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<AuthCubit>().resetPassword(_emailController.text.trim());
  }

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'Enter your email address and we will send you a password reset link',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                  fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 320,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
              key: const ValueKey('email'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email Address',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 320,
            height: 50,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
              onPressed: () => _passwordReset(context),
              child: Text(
                'Reset Password',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          SizedBox(
            width: 320,
            height: 50,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text(
                'Go back to login screen',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Is it something related to flutter version? I have the latest flutter on my computer. When I do flutter clean and flutter pub get the error appears to go. But when I run the app, the error pops back and it is shown as error under the problems tab.

probably related to the latest changes there https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/material-state which flutter SDK have you set in your apps pubsepc?

version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
sdk: ">=3.1.5 <4.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

What do you mean by ìs not recognized`?

while I run the app, its giving build error for all instances of WidgetStatePropertyAll. Otherwise before run, there is no error. As soon as I run, it gives the error back.

please add this errors output to your question and also that this happens when you run the app

okay, that was added

where did you add it?

" is giving me error" is a very vague description. Please provide exactly what the errror says

It's a build error

still vague. We need the full sentence error that you get. "it's a build error" is not helpful at all. What is the actual error?! Type it out exactly how you see it

The method 'WidgetStatePropertyAll' isn't defined for the type '_ForgotPasswordPageState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WidgetStatePropertyAll'. (in the problems tab).

In recent versions of Flutter, MaterialState has been moved outside of the Material library and renamed WidgetState. As a result, you'll need to use WidgetStatePropertyAll instead of deprecated MaterialStatePropertyAll. While it's unclear why an error occurs instead of a deprecation warning, this change is likely the cause.
See the migration guide for this change at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/material-state.
